# Gradle jar task fails with "Failed to capture snapshot of output files for task 'jar' property 'archivePath' during up-to-date check."

Tags: gradle, jar

i have this jar task in my gradle file that looks like this:

```
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes "Main-Class": "nameSpace.myClass"
    }

    from {
        configurations.compile.collect {
            it.isDirectory() ? it : project.zipTree(it).matching {
                exclude 'META-INF/*.RSA', 'META-INF/*.SF', 'META-INF/*.DSA','build','.gradle/**','build.gradle','gradle','gradlew','gradlew.bat','test'
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Running the jar task seldom renders a successful result. Most of the times it gives me the following error:

```
* What went wrong:
Failed to capture snapshot of output files for task 'jar' property 'archivePath' during up-to-date check.
> Failed to create MD5 hash for file 'PATH/build/libs/filename.jar'.
```

Running the task with --stacktrace and --debug gives me a few more data:

```
* Exception is:
13:21:45.559 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: Failed to capture snapshot of output files for task 'jar' property 'archivePath' during up-to-date check.
```

A little bit further down:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: PATH/build/libs/filename.jar (Permission denied)
```

Does anyone recognize this? I run OS X, and my colleague running Linux has never experienced this problem.

The jar task runs for quite a long time. This part seems to be the longest running parts:

```
13:54:08.324 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter] Executing actions for task ':jar'.
13:54:12.992 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.Daemon] DaemonExpirationPeriodicCheck running
13:54:12.994 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
13:54:12.994 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired.
13:54:12.994 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
13:54:12.995 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
13:54:12.995 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired.
13:54:12.996 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
13:54:22.993 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.Daemon] DaemonExpirationPeriodicCheck running
13:54:22.994 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
13:54:22.994 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired.
13:54:22.995 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
13:54:22.996 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
13:54:22.996 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired.
13:54:22.996 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
13:54:32.297 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter] Removed task artifact state for {} from context.
```

I have tried to run the clean task, delete the build folder, restarting the daemon etc, but nothing helps.

Edit: 
Upgrading Gradle to 3.3 did not solve anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is most likely an antivirus issue. Try disabling your antivirus and do it again. It happened to me. Very weird!

Comment: Wow, that never struck my mind. I will check it out first thing tomorrow

Comment: It actually seem to be the case for me as well. Thank you